# Django template 'IF' condition

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to do something like

```
{% if "sumit" in feed.like.person.all %}
```

But this gives me `TemplateSyntaxError`. How can I do this in Djagno ?

(Basically, I want to check if 'sumit' exists in feed.like.person.all)

Here are my relevant models.

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


class Like(models.Model):
    feed = models.OneToOneField(Feed)
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    person = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: This is not doable in the straight forward way in django templates. They aren't built for that purpose. Are you getting just one `feed` in the template? Is this only one condition you are checking or are there multiple similar conditions?

Comment: @AKS There are multiple `feeds` in the template. What I am trying to achieve is display the feed, and beneath that, if I have already liked that feed, I want to show, `you like this`.

Comment: Please check my answer for an optimized way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to check if a user likes a feed within the templates by querying for each feed is very inefficient.

I would suggest using [`Conditional Expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) to annotate each `feed` while fetching the queryset:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, When, Value

feeds = Feed.objects.all().annotate(
             is_liked=Case(
                When(like__person=request.user, then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BooleanField()))
```

This way you would be getting everything in one query only. And, then in the template you can just check `is_liked` on the feed:

```
{% if feed.is_liked %}You like this.{% endif %}
```

I haven't really executed this query but looking at the documentation it would be something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I think you intended to check the following:

```
# check if current user likes a feed
{% if request.user in feed.like.person.all %}
```

But if you are checking this for multiple feeds, then this method becomes inefficient. For multiple feeds, better approach is to use [`Annotations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) as mentioned by [@AKS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2549021/aks).

Comment: `{% if request.user in feed.like.person.all %}` is not working. And there are multiple feeds in the webpage, how can I send whether or not I like that post for every feed in the webpage ?

Comment: Is `'django.template.context_processors.request',`  in your context_processors settings.

Comment: my bad, I had originally disliked from the django-admin. Its working now.. `{% if user in feed.like.person.all %}` is working either. Thank you !

Comment: While it works it is a really inefficient way to check this for all the feeds in the template. A better way would be to annotate each feed in the view itself with whether the current user has liked it or not.

Comment: @AKS Yes, you are right. For checking multiple feeds this would become inefficient. Initially i was thinking that it would be single feed. Will add the annotation approach too for handling multiple feeds.